# Linux install on ps4 -bash: [ : : interger expression expected [psxita@psxitarch ~]$

Tags: linux, shell-script

Went through the installation process and got a black screen and couldn't regain signal after refreshing hdmi. Restarted and tried to boot Linux and I get this

```
-bash: [ : : interger expression expected
[psxita@psxitarch ~]$
```

and don't know where to go from here. Any suggestions on how to get Linux to boot from here or is there a fix. Total noob when it comes to shell scripts.

Comment: Does the Bash error message actually spell `interger` wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

All we can tell from that is that the `[` builtin command of the bash shell was invoked with any one of the arithmetic comparison operators (`-lt`, `-gt`, `-le`, `-ge`, `-eq`, `-ne`) but with at least one of the operands seemingly empty.

That could happen for instance if there was a:

```
if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]; then
```

line in one of [bash startup files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), and either `$a` or `$b` or both referred to empty or unset variables.

Try starting bash as `PS4=' $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO> ' bash --login -o xtrace` to see where the line is.